# Else if .value = 1 to 92 code check

Tags: vba

I've written code that selects column D and checks it for codes 1 to 92 however I have to write out c4.Value = 1 Or c4.Value = 2 all the way up to c4.Value = 92, is there a quicker way of doing this? Please see below for my code and I appreciate all help.

```
Sub q2country_and_q2country_other()


   Dim i As Long, c4 As Range, c5 As Range

   For i = 2 To 456
      Set c4 = Range("D" & i)
      Set c5 = Range("E" & i)

  If c4.Value = 94 Then
      Select Case c5.Value
      Case "", " ", "0", -99, -66, -77
         c4.Interior.color = vbRed
         c5.Interior.color = vbRed
      Case Else
         c4.Interior.color = vbGreen
         c5.Interior.color = vbGreen
   End Select

  ElseIf c4.Value = 1 Or c4.Value = 92 Then
      Select Case c5.Value
      Case -99, ""
         c4.Interior.color = vbGreen
         c5.Interior.color = vbGreen
      Case Else
         c4.Interior.color = vbRed
         c5.Interior.color = vbRed
      End Select

End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You can probably use a nested loop here, but I'm not quite sure how because I don't understand your *logic*. How are you deciding which color to apply to the interior? According to the sample you've shown here, it isn't always the same.

Comment: FWIW it seems to me that your logic can be passed into a conditional formatting rule, which would completely eliminate the need for VBA.

Comment: @CodyGray It seems to me that the correct solution is to use `Select Case c4.Value \n Case 94 \n 'first block \n Case 1 To 92 \n 'second block` or alternatively use an If-condition like `c4.Value >= 1 And c4.Value <= 92`

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys, it's a large file I'm working on with quite a few macros which was why I'm building the formatting in as a VBA check. The people in charge want "A button to make it all work" lol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only use the `To` syntax with `Case` statements inside a `Select` block, and you can nest `Select` Blocks....

Note that indentation helps enormously, so I've changed the indentation to 2 spaces, although 4 is more typical, but doesn't always suit StackExchange rendering.

```
Sub q2country_and_q2country_other()

   Dim i As Long, c4 As Range, c5 As Range

   For i = 2 To 456
      Set c4 = Range("D" & i)
      Set c5 = Range("E" & i)

      Select Case c4.Value
        Case 94 
          Select Case c5.Value
            Case "", " ", "0", -99, -66, -77
              c4.Interior.color = vbRed
              c5.Interior.color = vbRed
            Case Else
              c4.Interior.color = vbGreen
              c5.Interior.color = vbGreen
          End Select

        Case 1 To 92 
          Select Case c5.Value
            Case -99, ""
              c4.Interior.color = vbGreen
              c5.Interior.color = vbGreen
            Case Else
              c4.Interior.color = vbRed
              c5.Interior.color = vbRed
          End Select
      End Select
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: @Vogel612 has a suggestion that will work better in this particular instance, as the range is contiguous. `If c4.Value >= 1 And c4.Value <= 92 Then` will perform much faster than the `Case 1 to 92` approach.

Comment: Why do you say that an If statement will perform faster than Case x To y? I'm not disagreeing, I'm just wondering if this is theoretical, something you've benchmarked, or both.

Comment: As per @Comintern's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40945457/5757159) *The second optimization is to not use Case x To y syntax if you can avoid it. The reason has to do with how it compiles - it doesn't compile to a test like `Case = Condition >= x And Condition <= y`, it actually creates a loop with an early exit condition*

Comment: Cool—someone actually disassembled it. That's what I was hoping to see. Thanks for the reference!

Comment: @Hosey93 -  Noting a potential bug: what happens if `C4.Value = 93`? If you are expecting a change in `.Interior.Color`, it won't happen.

Comment: Oh I completely missed that, good catch. 93 should be red as the value isn't used, I'll factor this in thanks for the heads up @FreeMan!

Comment: No worries, @Hosey93 - it's always easier to find bugs in other people's code than in your own... :)